# How TO Concat " into an String in Eclipse?

Tags: android, database, eclipse, string

I want to fire a query by passing this "String", with the quotes?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Answer (score 4):

If you're doing this in code, you need to escape the quote marks:

```
String s = "\"String\"";
```

If you are defining a string resource value in XML, use the same technique:

```
<string name="s">\"String\"</string>
```

Then in code, `getResources().getString(R.string.s)` will be "String" (with the quotes).